# dart, how to get the symbol for a specific member?

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

What is the most efficient way of getting the symbol for a single member of a class?

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class TestClass{
    void iWantThisSymbol(){}
    void butNotThisOne(){}
}

/**
 * I can get all the symbols and filter down but this isn't nice
 */
void main(){
    var allSymbols = reflectClass(TestClass).instanceMembers.keys;
    var justTheSymbolIWant = allSymbols.where((symbol) => symbol.toString().contains('iWantThisSymbol')); // this doesnt seem very efficient or maintainable
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
var justTheSymbolIWant = reflectClass(TestClass).instanceMembers[#iWantThisSymbol]
```

Although, to be a bit pedantic, you're not get getting a Symbol, you're using a Symbol (`#iWantThisSymbol`) to get a member, which in this case is a method. So I would rewrite this as:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class TestClass{
    void iWantThisMethod(){}
    void butNotThisOne(){}
}

void main(){
    var justTheMethodIWant = reflectClass(TestClass).instanceMembers[#iWantThisMethod];
}
```

Also, a few things about that use of `where()`:

1. If you do want to filter a list of Symbols, you don't need to them convert to a String, you can just compare symbol instances directly.
2. `.where()` returns an iterable, even if there's only one item that matches. You probably want `firstWhere()` which always returns a single item.

```dart
var justTheSymbolIWant = allSymbols.firstWhere((symbol) => symbol == #iWantThisSymbol);
```

Comment: ah I completely forgot about the symbol literal syntax, thanks. though I didn't actually want the method that the symbol is for, I literally just wanted the symbol so I guess I could just rewrite it as `var justTheSymbolIWant = #iWantThisSymbol;` :)